# Animated radial Gradient with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/489eL/) i have a radial gradient as background-color.

Now i need to animate this to proceed 3 colours in a loop, while the center always be kept white:

```
- rgb(0, 69, 142)  // Blue
- rgb(0, 143, 51)  // Green
- rgb(156, 34, 54) // Red
```

I got some javascript for animated background-gradients, but nothin for the radial.

Can you please help me out?

### Solution

http://jsfiddle.net/489eL/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//Edit 
You have to workarround this because its not possible atm.

make Divs with position fixed and full width and height

give them all colours you want and fade them in

use z-index to set them behind your content

http://jsfiddle.net/63pAt/1/

//following is for non gradiant bgs i realised this doesnt work with gradiants sorry

```
<div id="bg"></div>
```

CSS

```
#bg {
-webkit-transition: background 5s ;
-moz-transition: background 5s ;
-ms-transition: background 5s ;
-o-transition: background 5s ;
transition: background 5s ;
//your gradiant styles
}


.second_state{
   //other background settings
 }
```

Javascript

```
$('#bg').addClass('second_state');
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Based on your impressive idea i got this final solution now: http://jsfiddle.net/489eL/4/